# How to make a table relationship?

Tags: sql, database-design

I want to make a web application to post reviews. As shown in the picture, there are three tables: User, Friends, and Review table. Users can add friends, and those Friends can write reviews as well as users.
What kind of relationship should we make in this case?
If there is a good way to do this, please tell me if the relationship between users and reviews is 1:n, but should the same be 1:n for friends?

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: User and Friend is the same entity Man. They must be stored in one table. One Man can be a friend for multiple man and backward the man can have multiple friends, so the relation is M:N (many-to-many) which needs in additional adjacency table.

Answer (score 0):

Your tables already have fine relations. And yes both friends and Reviews Table will have 1:n relation with User table.

**Logical Explanation:**

For Each Entry in User table there can be multiple entries in friends or reviews table. But for each entry in friends the foreign key user_id will only point to a single record in User hence 1:n

**Technical Explanation:**

You have added foreign keys from in Reviews and Friends Table with reference to User Tale i.e User_id. It is the implementation of 1:n relationship where one's primary key is the foreign key for Many's side.

**A possible scenario:**
Friends are also users and can be extracted from user table. You can simply have three fields in friends table a primary key and two foreign keys user_id and friend_id both referring to User table primary key. This will resolve all your issues regarding friends and user relation.

Comment: Thank you for answering!

By having these three fields in the Friends table, does it also automatically create a relationship between the Friends table and the Review table?
By having these three fields in the friends table, does it also automatically create a relationship between the friends table and the review table?

Comment: That depends on your requirement. You can make a relation between friends and reviews table. Primary key of friends table will go as foreign key in review. so when you join three tables you will know that who was receiving and who was giving review